# How To Call A Method In A Remote Service Using Messenger From An Activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I went through a lot of stuff when getting into services.
So i have a remote service which connects to a server and has to send and receive incoming messages and i used a remote service to do this because i need it to run almost all the time and also make notifications.
I used Messenger to communicate between the activity and service which uses the `IBinder` object to pass the messenger.I want to call a function from the activity in `OnServiceConnected();` to connect to the server but i cannot call functions in the service from the activity as in the [Service Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)
the way to call functions is through the IBinder but it is already used by the messenger.So is there a way to call a function from the activity without changing the `Messenger` part so what should i do?
And If u don't understand what i just said feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround so what i did was. I connected to the server by calling the `Connect()`function which i had from the service's `onCreate()` method so i connected on creation and when in need to send a message to the server, from the activity i used Messenger to send a string to the service to call the `sendMessage()` method.  This Server is a socket server in case anyone was thinking